# Spring boot active directory does only verify on unprotected endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

## Setup:

- Spring Boot 2.0.3 backend with spring security and azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter -> That does most things automatically
- Angular frontend (most probably irrelevant, as the issue is also present when testing in Postman).
  I can successfully obtain a valid JWT token from Microsoft in the frontend and provide it in the authorization header.

## Situation/Steps to reproduce the behaviour:

1. If I access a protected endpoint of the backend, it throws a 403 error instead of letting me through. (Any Endpoint except a specific one, as configured in `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();`)
2. If I access an unprotected endpoint, it not only works, but also verifies my sent token, as it outputs in the server log message. It also returns a JSESSIONID cookie. (Currently as in the /authorize endpoint)
3. Every following request to any protected endpoint now works, as the JSESSIONID cookie now lets the user pass through spring security.

## Question (more focused):

Is it intended by the microsoft library that every user should first obtain a JSESSIONID by sending a request with a JWT token in the authorization header to an unprotected endpoint? Directly following: If not: can I change that behaviour?

## Code:

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // allow all request access this url
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authorize").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    // access to this url requires authentication
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

Representative section of the rest service file:

```
  //unprotected
  @GetMapping(value = "/authorize")
  public String authorize() {
    return null;
  }

  //this site should ideally also be accessible with bearer token, not only with valid JSESSIONID
  @GetMapping(value = "/testsite2")
  public String testsite2() {

    return "test";
  }
```

**Edit:** Security related parts of the POM.xml

```xml
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Edit 2 for clarification**
This is actually all the necessary configuration to reproduce the problem. As far as I know (and I thoroughly searched, again), there is nothing additional security-relevant in there. Just the application.properties values with the microsoft data like clientId etc. No relevant configuration data besides that. 
I do not know where the JSESSIONID or the JWT token are verified, that is done automatically by the framework.

Comment: *Is that intended that way?* It is your configuration, hence you should know if it is intended. If you didn't intend it, then you misconfigure your configuration.

Comment: *Should every user first obtain a JSESSIONID from an unprotected endpoint?* Also that depends on application. Do you want it? If you don't want it, you have to change your application. There are several reasons for creating a HTTP session, for example a JSP page.

Comment: *Is there any way to verify the Bearer token even on a protected endpoint, if necessary?* I can't see that you verify the bearer token at all. You have to show that code, propably another Spring Security configuration.

Comment: The Problem for all those three questions is: I dont know. All of that (including ALL verification of JSESSIONID or Bearer Token) runs automatically and is poorly documented. This is literally all relevant code, but the configuration happens somewhere down there where I cannot see it. Clarification: If I approach the unprotected endpoint with a wrong Bearer Token, it gives me a JSESSIONID but that ID cannot be used for the other endpoints - they will throw a 403 nonetheless.

Comment: Did you really read the documentation? Your code doesn't look like the example. Also the documentation explains, how to use it in a stateless application.